# Why does @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class) give the error "This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property with backing field'"

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, android-testing

I am again working through a [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-basics-kotlin-affirmations-test-lists-and-adapters?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-unit-2-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-affirmations-test-lists-and-adapters#4) at developer.android.com.
Here's the code I believe is relevant to my question

build.gradle:

```
...
dependencies {

    ...
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
}
```

AffirmationsListTests.kt:

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
import androidx.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*
import androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
class AffirmationsListTests {
    @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
    @get:Rule
    val activity = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)
    @Test
    fun scroll_to_item(){
        onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view)).perform(
            RecyclerViewActions
                .scrollToPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(7))

        onView(withText(R.string.affirmation8))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
}
```

The line `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)` has the wavy red underline and the problems pane says "This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property with backing field'"

Have I made an mistake, or is there a problem with the codelab?

Comment: The `@RunWith` is a class annotation, it must be above the `class` definition.

Comment: Thanks. The instructions just said "Add a test runner to the newly created class." not "Add a test runner above the newly created class." Hence my error. If you'd care to expand that into an answer, I'll accept it.